# Excluding 'duplicated' scraped URLs in Python app?

Tags: python

I've never used Python before so excuse my lack of knowledge but I'm trying to scrape a xenforo forum for all of the threads. So far so good, except for the fact its picking up multiple URLs for each page of the same thread, I've posted some data before to explain what I mean.

```
forums/my-first-forum/: threads/my-gap-year-uni-story.13846/
forums/my-first-forum/: threads/my-gap-year-uni-story.13846/page-9
forums/my-first-forum/: threads/my-gap-year-uni-story.13846/page-10
forums/my-first-forum/: threads/my-gap-year-uni-story.13846/page-11
```

Really, what I would ideally want to scrape is just one of these.

```
forums/my-first-forum/: threads/my-gap-year-uni-story.13846/
```

Here is my script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_source(url):
    return requests.get(url).content

def is_forum_link(self):
    return self.find('special string') != -1

def fetch_all_links_with_word(url, word):
    source = get_source(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    return soup.select("a[href*=" + word + "]")

main_url = "http://example.com/forum/"

forumLinks = fetch_all_links_with_word(main_url, "forums")
forums = []

for link in forumLinks: 
    if link.has_attr('href') and link.attrs['href'].find('.rss') == -1:
        forums.append(link.attrs['href']);

print('Fetched ' + str(len(forums)) + ' forums')

threads = {}

for link in forums: 
    threadLinks = fetch_all_links_with_word(main_url + link, "threads")

    for threadLink in threadLinks:
        print(link + ': ' + threadLink.attrs['href'])
        threads[link] = threadLink

print('Fetched ' + str(len(threads)) + ' threads')
```

Comment: Btw This code is broken. It ain't class yet you have `self` involved.

Comment: It isn't broken because that function never gets executed.

Comment: Is what comes after the part of the url you want always going to be "page..."?

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that what should be removed from the url to check for uniqueness is always going to be "/page-#...". If that is not the case this solution will not work.

Instead of using a list to store your urls you can use a set, which will only add unique values. Then in the url remove the last instance of "page" and anything that comes after it if it is in the format of "/page-#", where # is any number, before adding it to the set.

```
forums = set()

for link in forumLinks: 
    if link.has_attr('href') and link.attrs['href'].find('.rss') == -1:
        url = link.attrs['href']
        position = url.rfind('/page-')
        if position > 0 and url[position + 6:position + 7].isdigit():
            url = url[:position + 1]
        forums.add(url);
```

Comment: This doesn't ensure its at the end, neither does it ensure there is `-` and a number after `/page`.

Comment: Can you give a better example of your urls then? In this example it will find "/page". which in your example could only occur at the end. Do you have cases where /page could be found multiple times in the same url?

Comment: Technically, it could be in the string multiple times, for example if the thread title contained the word 'page', I need to match if the string ends with '/page-*', the * being a wild card and a digit.

Comment: OK, I made an update based on this. It will now find the last instance of /page- and check the next character to see if it is a number.